# Prove that the norm in an inner product space is $ \ge 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, inner-products

[Macdonald Linear and Geometric Algebra](http://faculty.luther.edu/~macdonal/laga/) defines an Inner Product Space in the following way (pg 57):

"An *inner product space* is a vector space with a product called an inner product. The inner product of two vectors is a scalar. Axioms $I1-I4$ must be satisfied for all scalars $a$ and all vectors $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}.$

$$
I1.\ (a\mathbf{u})\cdot\mathbf{v} = a(\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v})
$$
$$  
I2.\ (\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v})\cdot\mathbf{w} = \mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{w}+\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{w} 
$$
$$  
I3.\ \mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{u} 
$$
$$
I4.\ If \ \mathbf{v} \neq \mathbf{0}, then \ \mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{v} > 0
$$"

Furthermore, the norm is defined in the following way (pg 58):

"The *norm* of a vector $\mathbf{v}$ in an inner product space is given by $|\mathbf{v}|^2 = \mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{v}$."

This is slightly unconventional (to me) in the sense that every other linear algebra text I've looked at defines the norm as $\sqrt{\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{v}}$. The Macdonald definition leaves open the possibility that $|\mathbf{v}|$ could be less than zero. However, we are indeed then asked to prove (pg 59):

"$N1.\ If \ \mathbf{v} \neq \mathbf{0}, |\mathbf{v}| > 0.$"

...and so the definitions are equivalent. But I can't see how to prove that from only the definitions given. What am I missing?

Comment: I4 does the job, or?

Comment: no, 14 only proves the norm is real

Comment: I agree with SRX below that it is better to say the other way. Also on page 3 of the book, the author defined the norm as the length of an Oriented length, denoted by $|v|$. He then mentioned on page 51 "Recall that the length, or norm, of $v$ is denoted $|v|$". With these context, the definition sounds justifiable.

Comment: The norm given for an oriented length is a specific example. This is a general definition of a norm for any inner product space. Therefore it must be provable just from the axioms and definition given.

Comment: @Hrodelbert: What do you mean with `proves only the norm is real`? If $\mathbf v\neq 0$, then $\mathbf v\cdot \mathbf v >0$. In which case could we have   $\mathbf v\cdot \mathbf v <0$?

Comment: @OTBC: I see. Maybe you can send the author a comment. I think he should really define it in the conventional way.

Comment: I have added some comments in my answers. Hope it explains my thoughts better.

Comment: Also as an FYI,  I3 is only true for a real inner product space...if the underlying field is complex,  you need conjugate symmetry.

Comment: @SRX I might email the author to clarify. But he specifically chose the definition given (it's verbatim from the book) and then asked that the reader prove the norm is non-negative. Otherwise he could've just defined the norm as being the positive square root of the inner product and saved a couple of paragraphs :-)

Comment: @Bernard The statement $v\cdot v >0$ is always true, but this only implies that the rhs of $|v|^2 =v\cdot v$ is positive and thus that the solution $|v|$ of this equation is real.

Answer (score 1):

When we say a $|\cdot|$ is a norm, we already assume its non-negativity, by the original definition of a norm. So by saying
$$|\mathbf{v}|^2 = \mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{v}$$
the author actually means
$$|\mathbf{v}| = \sqrt{\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{v}}$$
as you usually read, or otherwise it does not define a norm. But I think it is clearer to say "a norm is induced by $|\mathbf{v}|^2 = \mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{v}$" rather than "the norm is given by $|\mathbf{v}|^2 = \mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{v}$", since the original definition of a norm does not come from an inner product.

**Added:**
$|\mathbf{v}| \geq 0$ is true by definition of a norm. If the non-negativity is not clear, then calling it a norm is not legit, as it has not fulfilled the original definition of a norm. If you are showing $|\mathbf{v}| \geq 0$ for all $\mathbf{v}$, you are not showing "the norm is nonnegative" but "$|\cdot|$ is a norm". So no matter he writes $|\mathbf{v}|^2 = \mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{v}$ is a norm or $|\mathbf{v}| = \sqrt{\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{v}}$ is a norm, it is not a new definition but some kind of a proposition. Anyway, I agree that the author should be more specific in writing the statement.

Comment: But if the author assumes its non-negativity, why does he ask for it to be proved?

Comment: @OTBC: I think he asks you to show that it is not equal to 0, instead of disprove negativity.

Comment: I am not sure, probably it is just a rather trivial one-line proof using I4.

Comment: @KittyL The requirement is to prove the norm of a vector is always >= 0.